# Unable to load the page with jQuery get

Tags: jquery, get

Just came across Get method. I'm trying to dig it deeper. Your help would be massively appreciated.

I am trying to fetch the page content from this page
https://broadband.comparethemarket.com/packages?location=e177bf#/?broadbandType=Standard,Fibre&btSport=&cartoonNetwork=&comedyCentral=&contractLength=&discoveryChannel=&disneyChannel=&firstYearCost=&newLine=&phoneCalls=Show%20me%20everything&productType=broadband,phone&providers=&sky1=&skyAtlantic=&skyCinema=&skyLiving=&skySports=&sortBy=First%20Year%20Cost&speedInMb=17Mb&tab=alldeals&usage=UsageLimitedOption,UsageUnlimitedOption

onto this page
https://broadband.comparethemarket.com/?AFFCLIE=CM01#/?productType=broadband,phone
using Get method

I am doing it the following way

```
$.get(urlString, function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

urlString is the first url

I am unable to pull through the content. it only brings in few elements and not the search results from that page. 
Could you please put me in the right direction. 
Thanks

Comment: That web page uses Javascript to create the content. `$.get()` won't run the Javascript.

Comment: It's probably using AJAX to get the content. You should call that AJAX service directly, instead of trying to scrape this HTML page.

Comment: @Barmar could you give me an example please of calling Ajax service

Comment: Use `$.ajax()`. You'll need to find out the parameters to the AJAX service that the page is using.

Comment: I used `$.ajax(urlString, function(data) {
console.log(data)
 });` with no luck. not sure how to find the parameters. Please could you explain it bit more.

Comment: You need to use a different URL string, the URL that's used internally by the Javascript on that web page. In other words, you have to reverse engineer what that web page is doing.

Comment: @Barmar hmm any idea what that would be in the case of above url. sorry I am bit clueless atm.

Comment: You should contact the site to find out if they have a public API you can use. They should be able to provide the documentation of how to call it.